# How can i add a value to a cell via SQL

Tags: sql

I was just asked to update a table in SQL that has a column with a range of numbers. I need to add 10 to each value, unless it is 0 or 65.

I am new to SQL ... thanks

Comment: what have you tried? Stackoverflow is not here to do your work for you. Why don't you try reading some tutorials (e.g. http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlupdate.php)

Answer (score 2):

Best to way to no longer be "new" is to read/practice: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29

that being said:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourfield = yourfield + 10
WHERE (yourfield NOT IN (10, 65))
```

or

```
...
WHERE (yourfield <> 10) AND (yourfield <> 65)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this which performs an `UPDATE` on your column but excludes the records with either a `0` or `65`:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourCol = yourCol+10
WHERE yourCol NOT IN (0, 65)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/924e4/1)